# How to filter stored procedures as READ and WRITE in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Is there any query to get all the write procedures from SQL Server?

Comment: You can get the names, content and other information about stored procedures from `sys.procedures` - but there's no flag telling you whether it's a read-only or read-write procedure ...

Comment: Thanku, But i was looking for what kind of operations(read or write) it is doing..

Comment: A procedure can be a complex mix of all sorts of operations and may not be easily characterised as read or write - take care.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking for every Procedure containing `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` like this:

```
SELECT top 10 p.name, SCHEMA_NAME(p.schema_id), *
FROM sys.sql_modules as m
INNER JOIN sys.procedures as p ON p.object_id = m.object_id
WHERE definition like '%INSERT%'
    OR definition like '%UPDATE%'
    OR definition like '%DELETE%'
```

However it will also output any procedure with a variable, a comment or anything with a name containing `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE`.

You can add MERGE if your procedure may use it.

Comment: First of all, you've forgot the `MERGE` operation - and by just simply string parsing, you could also be mislead if you something like `SELECT (list-of-columns) FROM dbo.InsertStaging ......` - that would be flagged as a "write" procedure, even though it's clearly only doing a `SELECT`....